# Merge separate projects into one solution and not loose the history in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have 2 separate solutions in TFS, the structure is shown below:

```
App.A1
 App.A1.Web

App.A2
 App.A2.Core
 App.A2.Web
```

Now I want to merge it to one solution. Additionally, I want App.A2.Core to became common Core project for 2 Web projects, so finally it should look like below:

```
App.B
 App.B.Core
 App.B.A1.Web
 App.B.A2.Web
```

I'm using TFS. How it should be done not to loose history ?

Are the following steps:

1. Creating App.B solution folder in Source Control
2. Branching App.A1.Web, App.A2.Web and App.A2.Core to this folder
3. Changing names App.A1.Web -> App.B.A1.Web, App.A2.Web -> App.B.A2.Web, App.A2.Core -> App.B.Core

a good solution ?

Comment: I've done that this way, but used "Move" instead of "Branch"

Answer (score 0):

Renaming and moving files in TFS2010 will disconnect the history but not lose it.

So, if I move file X in folder A to folder B then the history of X starts again in B.  It will however still be in A (if you switch on the ability to see deleted files) where you can view the full history of X.

Similar story if you rename file X to be Y.  The history of Y starts, the "deleted" X still has full history.

What this means for you is that the history is never lost.

As for what you want to do here's what I'd do:

1. Repurpose the App.A1 solution as App.B solution
2. Move all the App.A2 projects to be with the App.A1/B solution
3. Delete the App.A2 solution